# Core Plot: how to remove CPTGraph padding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot

I can't get rid of the gaps between CPTGraph border and CPTPlotAreaFrame inside.

The dark gray color on this example is CPTGraph and the light gray is CPTPlotAreaFrame. Both of them have frame size of `{ 150, 150 }`.

[image]

What is the property that controls CPTGraph padding? CPTPlotAreaFrame's `paddingBottom` and others control internal padding of CPTPlotAreaFrame.

Here's the code.

```
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:hostingView];

CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectToCGRect(hostingView.bounds)];
graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor grayColor]];
graph.axisSet = nil;
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

// both of these are { 150.0, 150.0 }
NSLog(@"%f %f", graph.frame.size.width, graph.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"%f %f", graph.plotAreaFrame.frame.size.width, graph.plotAreaFrame.frame.size.height);

graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor lightGrayColor]];
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;

CPTPieChart *piePlot = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
piePlot.dataSource = self.viewModel;
piePlot.pieRadius = MIN( CPTFloat(0.7) * (hostingView.frame.size.height - CPTFloat(2.0) * graph.paddingLeft) / CPTFloat(2.0),
                         CPTFloat(0.7) * (hostingView.frame.size.width - CPTFloat(2.0) * graph.paddingTop) / CPTFloat(2.0) );
piePlot.identifier = self.title;
piePlot.startAngle = CPTFloat(M_PI_4);
piePlot.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionCounterClockwise;

piePlot.labelRotationRelativeToRadius = YES;
piePlot.labelRotation = CPTFloat(-M_PI_2);
piePlot.labelOffset = -50.0;

piePlot.delegate = self;
[graph addPlot:piePlot];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the padding on the `graph` itself. A `CPTGraph` starts with 20 pixels of padding on each side.

```
graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
graph.paddingTop = 0.0;
graph.paddingRight = 0.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;
```

Comment: Huh, silly me! I completely missed it somehow. Thanks!